# ManyToMany relationship between Category and Product in Ecommerce

Tags: python, django

I am developing a eCommerce using Django and relationship between Product and Category Models is Many-to-many. That is, one product can belong to several category.

In the product list page there is a sidebar showing the category list as well as the product list under each category. We use get_absolute_url method of Product to link to the url of each product detail page.

The problem is that in the product detail page (template), I do not know how to get the category name to this product, because this product may belong to several categories. I want to use the category of this product to make a breadcrumb.

Product model

```
class AbstractProduct(models.Model):
...
categories = models.ManyToManyField(
        'catalogue.Category',
        through='ProductCategory',
        verbose_name=_("Categories"))
...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('catalogue:detail', kwargs={'product_slug': self.slug, 'pk': self.id})
```

Product list template (prod.model is the model number of product)

```
<a href="{{ prod.get_absolute_url }}" class="nav-link text-muted mb-2">{{ prod.model }}</a>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'catalogue'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.list, name='list'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.list,  name='list_by_category'),
    path('<slug:product_slug>/<int:pk>', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that in the product detail page (template), I do not know how to get the category name to this product, because this product may belong to several categories. I want to use the category of this product to make a breadcrumb.

You need to solve this problem of how to determine which category should be used before you can move onto implementing the details. I can think of two options off the top of my head:

1. Keep track of the category in the session.
2. Include the category in the url for the product.

2 is the better option as it doesn't depend on some state to determine what's being rendered. If you keep track of the category in session, a user mid-session could clear their cookies, refresh the page and get an entirely different view. That's generally a bad thing.

You'll have to determine how to best design your urls based on your business logic. Typically it would be: `category/<category_id>/<product_slug>` as viewing a category should return multiple products. However, your application will dictate how to do this.

One consequence of this is that you will not be able to use `get_absolute_url` on product when viewing the product "within a category". The information to determine which category should be used in the url is on the request and will be available in the view, but won't be available on the product instance.